# Failed loading XML Start tag expected '<' not found

Tags: joomla-3.6, xml

I keep getting two messages on screen as soon as I enter my site "[image: FAILED LOADING XML]" or refresh a page after dismissing message and moving to a new tab, i.e from HOME to Subscribe. The site works 100%, the only problem is that messages. Link to live site: [CyberSec.group.](http://cybersec.group) I'm using Joomla 3.6.5 and the default Protostar template, together with a few additional addons, modules and components. The messages I get is not in any particular module, so it is kind of hard for me to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Are you using a Joomla article on the homepage or are you using something like K2? Also, have you made any code changes to any files other than the template?

Comment: Looks like a broken manifest file, deactivate every module. If the error is gone, activate every module one by one.

Comment: @Lodder No, there is nothing in that specific space where the message comes up. and yes, we have made changes when we built the site in December last year, but none that gave that error. only last week when I checked the site again did I find that error.

Comment: @DennisHeiden never tried that, will do, and respond with results